# How can I call setState of a child widget from a parent widget?

Tags: flutter

Whenever the user clicks on the back button of the device, I need to change a variable value inside the child widget and call `setState()`. The thing is that when I click the back button, the onWillPopScope() of the parent widget is called and not of the child widget. So, I need from the parent to change the variable value of the child widget state and call `setstate()` inside the child widget. Or if there is a way to do that the onWillPopScope of the child widget will be called, it would also solve my problem. Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to add a field to child widget then in parent widget change value of that field and call `setState()`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Parent extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ParentState createState() => _ParentState();
}

class _ParentState extends State<Parent> {
  String _text;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Child(param: _text),
          RaisedButton(
            child: const Text('CHANGE VALUE'),
            onPressed: () => _updateChild('NEW VALUE'),
          )
        ],
      );

  void _updateChild(String value) {
    _text = value;

    setState(() {});
  }
}

class Child extends StatefulWidget {
  final String param;

  const Child({this.param});

  @override
  _ChildState createState() => _ChildState();
}

class _ChildState extends State<Child> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Text(widget.param);
}
```